# Can't debug from Eclipse and Android Emulator when Visual Studio is debugging a web application

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010, debugging, android-emulator, conflict

**UPDATE:** It appears if I start Visual Studio debugger FIRST, then use Eclipse, it works! I must have done it in that order last time it worked, leaving this here with the hope to help someone else in the future.

Though I am not sure why this is happening, because it was working last week!

Basically I get either:

> The connection to adb is down, and a
>   severe error has occured.
>
> You must restart adb and Eclipse.
>
> Please ensure that adb is correctly
>   located at 'C:\dev\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be
>   executed.

or it manages to launch the emulator but then I get actual Java IO errors:

> An established connection was aborted by
>   the software in your host machine java.io.IOException: An established
>   connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

As soon as I closed Visual Studio completely I was able to successfully launch and debug the Android app in the emulator from Eclipse... though I was of course unable to browse my web application!

Could there be some kind of port conflict going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It appears if I start Visual Studio debugger FIRST, then use Eclipse, it works! I must have done it in that order last time it worked, leaving this here with the hope to help someone else in the future.

I'm guessing that Visual Studio is smarter than Eclipse, which is why it works one way and not the other, Eclipse won't try other ports maybe... not 100% on this, still willing to give the answer to whoever offers a true explanation to go with my 'solution'.